# Symfony server not starting

Tags: symfony, connect, host

I set up Symfony 3, and when I try to start the server here's what happens:

```
[heigold1@centos aqua_note]$ php bin/console server:start
[OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000    

[heigold1@centos aqua_note]$ (it goes back to the command prompt???) 

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]                              
Attempted to call function "posix_setsid" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle".  
    server:start [-d|--docroot DOCROOT] [-r|--router ROUTER] [--pidfile PIDFILE] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> [<addressport>]
```

And then when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000 I get the following message:

```
        This site can’t be reached

        127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing `php-posix` extension. Install it (ora enable it) to solve the problem.

See the output of `phpinfo()` to see which extension are installed.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this

```
yum install php-process
```

to enable posix. works for php71

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
php bin/console server:start --force
```

Because your server already start

**Or:** try call `--help`

```
php bin/console server:start --help

........................................................
```